# How to Replace src Attribute of <img> Tag from String in Android

Tags: java, android, html, html-parsing, android-webview

My Application is Client-Server Based Application in which I have to display images in `WebView` that are stored in `SDcard`.
Problem is that String which is stored from server end is like:

```
"<html><img id=\"MathMLEq1\" style=\"vertical-align: middle;\" src=\"/SOCH/img.PNG\" alt=\"\"/></html>"
```

I want to Add some characters before the value that is already defined in `src tag` Programmatically like:

```
"<html><img id=\"MathMLEq1\" style=\"vertical-align: middle;\" src=\"file:///mnt/sdcard/SOCH/img.PNG\" alt=\"\"/></html>"
```

Can Anybody help me through this..??
Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String inputString = "<html><img id=\"MathMLEq1\" style=\"vertical-align: middle;\" src=\"/SOCH/img.PNG\" alt=\"\"/></html>";
StringBuffer q= new StringBuffer(inputString);
String add = "file:///mnt/sdcard";
int separatedInd = inputString.indexOf("/SOCH"); //Get the index of occurrence of the folder name in input string, which I assume remains same
q = q.insert(separatedInd ,add); //Insert your String at that index( before start of /SOCH)
String result = q.toString();  // Contains the new final string which you require
```

**Updated code:**

As you commented that you may have more than one occurrence of `<img>` tag in the same String, here is the updated code to replace the strings at all desired places:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// Assuming three times here
String inputString = "<html><img id=\"MathMLEq1\" style=\"vertical-align: middle;\" src=\"/SOCH/img.PNG\" alt=\"\"/></html> <html><img id=\"MathMLEq1\" style=\"vertical-align: middle;\" src=\"/SOCH/img.PNG\" alt=\"\"/></html> <html><img id=\"MathMLEq1\" style=\"vertical-align: middle;\" src=\"/SOCH/img.PNG\" alt=\"\"/></html>";
StringBuffer q= new StringBuffer(inputString);
String add = "file:///mnt/sdcard";
//Get all indexed of the occurrence of /SOCH string
for (int index = inputString.indexOf("/SOCH");
     index >= 0;
     index = inputString.indexOf("/SOCH", index + 1)){

    arrayList.add(index); //add the indexes to arrayList
}
int prev = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++){ // for all indexes
    q = q.insert(prev+ arrayList.get(i),add); //Insert the add string at position (index + (number of times 'add' string appears * length of 'add' string)  
    prev = (i+1)*add.length(); // calculate the next position where to insert the string

}
String result = q.toString(); //Gives the final output as desired.
```

Hope this helps

Comment: buddy thanks for your response, but i have multiple occurrence of `<img> tag` in one string how to replace them all with the same string `"file:///mnt/sdcard"`..??

Comment: Is the folder name `SOCH` same in all the `<img>` tags or it differs?

Comment: See updated code. It adds the desired string at all the desired places/occurrences of `<img>` tag in same string.

Comment: budyy thanks alot.. your code worked perfectly for me... thanks alot once again..

Comment: Glad it helped you :). Through the course of my limited experience, I've felt that the way to go for solving such problems is almost the same. Just think how your brain comes to know where to add that string. You scroll your eyes throughout the string(for loop to get the index), look for a pattern like `src` or `/SOCH`(string of whose index to find) and then insert it there. Break the same flow of thought into smaller steps and you are almost done.

Comment: yup buddy you are right... but as i am new to development i am not aware of the classes that are already available in android or java.. but hoping that will soon get a good vision of solving problem as you have.. thanks again buddy..

Comment: You need not necessarily know the classes but can start googling the shorter steps that you think are feasible. Rest assured, Stackoverflow is always for your rescue.

Comment: You actually got the thing what i actually do.. i go with the long solutions.. i just need to learn how to shorten steps of my logic with minimum steps feasible.. that the key to good programming.. thanks for your advice buddy..

Answer (score 0):

Try with [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/) library. You can get the tag's attributes with it, and when you got it, then you simply use JAVA-s *replace* method. Be carefull with the special characters in java string(such as /). You can write it into a string like this `"\""` . Read [this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30241&seqNum=3) about special characters.